# Get value from first lead row that has a different value

Tags: pyspark, window-functions

I have a list of ids, a sequence number of messages (seq) and a value (e.g. timestamps). Multiple rows can have the same sequence number. There are some other columns with different values in every row, but I excluded them as they are not important.

Within all messages from a deviceId (=partitionBy), I need to sort by sequence_number (=orderBy) and add the 'ts'-value of the **next message with a different sequence_number** to all messages of the current sequence_number.

I got so far as to retrieve the value of the next row *if that row has a different sequence number*. But since the "next row with a different sequence number" could potentially be `x` rows far away, I would have to add specific `.when(condition, ...)` blocks for `x` rows ahead.

I was wondering if there was a better solution which works no matter how "far away" the next row with a different sequence number is. I tried a `.otherwise(lead(col("next_value"), 1)`, but since I am just building the column, it doesn't work.

My Code & reproducible example:

```
data = [
    (1, 1, "A"),
    (2, 1, "G"),
    (2, 2, "F"),
    (3, 1, "A"),
    (4, 1, "A"),
    (4, 2, "B"),
    (4, 3, "C"),
    (4, 3, "C"),
    (4, 3, "C"),
    (4, 4, "D")
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=["id", "seq", "ts"])

df.printSchema()
df.show(10, False)


window = Window \
    .orderBy("id", "seq") \
    .partitionBy("id")
# I could potentially do this 100x if the next lead-value is 100 rows away, but I wonder if there isn't a better solution.
is_different_seq1 = lead(col("seq"), 1).over(window) != col("seq")
is_different_seq2 = lead(col("seq"), 2).over(window) != col("seq")

df = df.withColumn("lead_value",
                   when(is_different_seq1,
                        lead(col("ts"), 1).over(window)
                        )
                   .when(is_different_seq2,
                        lead(col("ts"), 2).over(window)
                    )

                   )

df.printSchema()
df.show(10, False)
```

Ideal output in column "next_value" for `id=4`:

| id | seq | ts | next_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 1 | A | B |
| 4 | 2 | B | C |
| 4 | 3 | C | D |
| 4 | 3 | C | D |
| 4 | 3 | C | D |
| 4 | 4 | D | Null |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried the more complicated case, so this might still need more adjustment but I think you can combine with `last` function.

With just the `lead` function, it results in like this.

| id | seq | ts | lead_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 1 | A | B |
| 4 | 2 | B | C |
| 4 | 3 | C | C |
| 4 | 3 | C | C |
| 4 | 3 | C | D |
| 4 | 4 | D | Null |

You want to overwrite the `lead_value` of 3rd and 4th rows to be "D" which is the last value of the `lead_value` in the same `id`&`seq` group.

```py
lead_window = (Window
    .partitionBy("deviceId")
    .orderBy("seq"))

last_window = (Window
    .partitionBy('deviceId', 'seq')
    .rowsBetween(0, Window.unboundedFollowing)) 

df = df.withColumn('next_value', F.last(
        F.lead(F.col('ts')).over(lead_window)
    ).over(last_window))
```

Result.

| id | seq | ts | next_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 1 | A | B |
| 4 | 2 | B | C |
| 4 | 3 | C | D |
| 4 | 3 | C | D |
| 4 | 3 | C | D |
| 4 | 4 | D | Null |

Comment: With the small example, this is faster than the `join` solution.  Let me know if this works accurately and more performant or not with your larger dataset.

Comment: Worked perfectly. It's consistently 2-3x faster than my solution!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution (horribly slow however), so if someone comes up with a better solution, please add your answer!

I get one row per "message" with a distinct, execute the lead(1) there, and join it back to the dataframe to the rest of the columns.

```
df_filtered = df.select("id", "seq", "ts").distinct()
df_filtered = df_filtered.withColumn("lead_value", lead(col("ts"), 1).over(window))
df = df.join(df_filtered, on=["id", "seq", "ts"])
```